# How to make landscape mode rotate properly in a twoside book?

Tags: landscape, double-sided

How can I use `pdflscape` (or some other?) package in a twoside book so that landscape mode is always rotated so that top of the page points to the middle of the book? By default it seems landscape mode does not do that?

So I would like to have from time to time a page in a landscape mode, but it should be rotated correctly. This will probably make some landscape pages hard to read on a screen, as they will be flipped, but it would be much better printed.

Comment: To which style or standard are you referring? AFAIK landscape images should be rotated so that the top faces left, on both sides of the book. This way the book needs to be rotated clockwise to read the landscape material.

Comment: `book` document class, no special style or standard. Just I thought it would would nicer to look like that?

Answer (score 3):

If you use [`rotating`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/rotating/) then the default, for two-sided documents, is to rotate the page according to the page number. I think this is exactly what you want.

Unfortunately `rotating` doesn't do the same thing as `pdflscape`, in that the pages are not rotated in the PDF viewer. I found [this related](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/msg/02c39273e57ab4cb) newsgroup message, but I don't believe there was ever a resolution.

But you say you're most concerned with the final printed output anyway, so I think `rotating` should be fine for your purposes?

Comment: There was an answer to my question on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982219/how-to-make-landscape-mode-rotate-properly-in-a-twoside-book/5320962#5320962) some time ago.